# FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) in Flutterinsta Package

Tags: flutter, dart, exception

I am using FlutterInsta package. I am getting some information after entering username in textfield. But i am getting this kind of exception after some time.

This is the error :-
I/flutter ( 8708): FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
I/flutter ( 8708): 
I/flutter ( 8708): ^

Here is the code :-

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Instainfo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  FlutterInsta flutterInsta = new FlutterInsta();

  var text;
  String url,followers,following,bio,username,website;
  List<String> feed = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body:ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: [
              TextField(
                onChanged: (val) {
                  text = val;
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.send),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      try {
                        await flutterInsta.getProfileData(text);
                        setState(() {
                          followers = flutterInsta.followers;
                          following = flutterInsta.following;
                        });
                      } catch (e) {
                        print(e);
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                  hintText: "Enter Username",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
             Column(
                children: [
                  Text("Followers :- $followers"),
                  Text("Following :- $following")
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Is there any limit to request this package ?

Comment: did you use any `http` call? It is response error for your API

Comment: No i haven't use http call